# Post repeating in Infinite Scroll in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, scroll, infinite

I have used Infinite Scroll with Masonry, and used below query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'author' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

        //DIV COMES HERE

          endwhile;
         endif;
```

Issue, its that same post are repeating again and again in Infinite Scroll.

Means I have Post 01, Post 02, Post 03, Post 04 on page load.. after scrolling down Post 01, Post 02, Post 03, Post 04, Post 05, Post 06, Post 07 and again Post 01, Post 02, Post 03, Post 04.. is repeating..

Comment: Try this extension: https://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below link for adding infinite scroll to wordpress

http://wptheming.com/2012/03/infinite-scroll-to-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any plugin that is named as "infinite posts scroll" or "jetpack" or any thing similar delete it. 
If not then try this:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        #var_dump($query);
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
    echo "<h2>Not Found</h2>";
}
```

Comment: but i need infinite scroll jquery